# removing values from data frame based on percentage change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate percentage change in price for a series data.
data is of below format

```
product   time    Price
ACB       2017-01  100
ACB       2017-02  102
ACB       2017-03  101
ACB       2017-04  140
ACB       2017-05  130
ACB       2017-06  105
```

Now i need to calculate the percent change of price over this time period.
Once we calculate the values, it will be in below format

```
product   time    Price   percnt_change
ACB       2017-01  100       
ACB       2017-02  102     0.02
ACB       2017-03  101    -0.0098
ACB       2017-04  140     0.386139
ACB       2017-05  130    -0.07143
ACB       2017-06  105    -0.19231
```

My requirement is to remove the values which crosses 10% changes (both positive and negative).
I tried to remove the value using below formula

```
df2=df1_remove.loc[lambda df1_remove:abs(df1_remove.percnt_change)<=.1]
```

so from above dataframe, we will remove 2017-04 and 2017-06 values.

```
product   time    Price  percnt_change
ACB       2017-01  100      
ACB       2017-02  102     0.02
ACB       2017-03  101    -0.0098
ACB       2017-05  130    0.2871
```

if i calculate percent change function again, then 2017-05 is out of my acceptable variance. Instead of doing this operation multiple times, is there any effective method to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df[df.percnt_change.abs() <= 0.1]` might be more efficient than your lambda expression. If you iterate here, I think you end up with an empty dataframe or you would have to find a good way to deal with the `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your comment, it seems like this might be what you're after.  I stand corrected in that you probably will need a loop here.  Say you have:

```
print(data)

  product    time  Price
0     ACB 2017-01    100
1     ACB 2017-02    102
2     ACB 2017-03    101
3     ACB 2017-04    140
4     ACB 2017-05    130
5     ACB 2017-06    105
```

To get to your desired output use:

```
def check_outliers(df, threshold=0.10):
    return df['Price'].pct_change().abs().gt(threshold).any()

while True:
    data['percnt_change'] = data['Price'].pct_change()
    mask = data['percnt_change'].abs() < 0.10
    data = data.loc[mask]
    if not check_outliers(data):
        break
```

What this does:

- `check_outliers` calculates an (updated) percentage change and returns True if any of the changes' absolute value exceeds threshold.
- A `while True` loop in itself is an infinite loop.  `data` is continually updated until there are no outliers remaining, at which the loop is broken out of.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my issue is after removing the outlier - i need to recalculate the percent change value. In above data, 101 to 130 percentage change is actually .2871. So when i recalculate , 2017-05 percnt_change value would be ,.2871 and this is outside my deviation limit, So i need to remove again.

Comment: I see what you mean.  revising now

Answer (score -1):

You can just iterate through rows from the oldest ones to the newest and at each step decide if it is to be removed or not, comparing it to the last row that was not removed (`accepted_rows[-1]`):

```
all_rows = [...]
accepted_rows = all_rows[0:1] # initially just first row

for current_row in all_rows[1:]:
    if price_change_between(accepted_rows[-1], current_row) <= 0.1:
        accepted_rows.append(current_row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my data set, there can be multiple products. How can i use above logic in that scenario Thanks again

Comment: Could you please provide some code? I'd like to see how your dataset is defined - then I can help you more with the actual Python implementation.